# Ignore folder in Perforce Folder Diff

Tags: .net, perforce

I am using Perforce for a .NET project.
I have not added bin and obj folders (created when the project builds) in the repository.
When I launch the Folder difference between Workspace and Repository, it shows the bin and obj folders.
I want to ignore the bin and obj folders from the perforce Folder Diff tool.
How to do this?

Comment: Is this something that you're attempting to do from either P4V or P4Win, or from the command line?

Comment: why is this so hard to do in perforce??

Answer (score 0):

You can always add exclusions to your workspace view, to prevent the bin and obj directories from being considered.  I assume you're using P4V's Reconcile Offline Work tool, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it whit this:

```
-//depot/foo/*.dll //USER/foo/*.dll
-//depot/foo/.../*.dll //USER/foo/.../*.dll
```

There's also a solution if you like to apply this to all workspaces. (Just an example)

```
write user * * -//.../*.bin
write user * * -//.../*.obj
write user * * -//.../*.ccscc
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to ignore a folder. In my case, I would like perforce to ignore the .git/ folder XD

Answer (score 0):

You could use P4IGNORE. Create a file `p4ignore` in your project directory, point the P4IGNORE variable to it and let the file have the following content:

```
# Ignore p4ignore files
p4ignore

# Ignore the bin directory
bin/
obj/
```

Now `p4 reconcile -n` or `p4 status` ignore bin and obj. Reconcile gives the status on diffs between the server and the workspace. It is more suited than diff here.

More details are here: https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.2/manuals/cmdref/P4IGNORE.html

Comment: does the p4 ignore file have to be in the project directory? does the environment variable P4IGNORE have to be an absolute path?

Comment: No, it can be anywhere with read access for the current user.